# Что то не могу разобрать массив...

Tags: php, json

Подскажите как разобрать такой массив:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [report] => stdClass Object
        (
            [count] => 2
            [clip] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [title] => Название
                            [id] => 234
                        )
                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [title] => Название 2
                            [id] => 235
                        )
```

Вот нужно получить id

Comment: Это не массив, а объект. Как следствие, к свойствам нужно обращаться используя нотацию `->`.

Comment: Ну так вот и не получается)))

Comment: Я конечно могу преобразовать его именно в массив, в заголовке накосячил - да)

Comment: Ну так вы опишете, что **конкретно** не получается. А то у меня хрустальный шар сломался.

Comment: добавьте второй параметр `true` в `json_decode`, раз нужен массив

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не совсем массив:

```
   <?php $item = new stdClass();
      echo $item->report->clip[0]['id'];
    ?>
```

Ну а коли он нужен длинней:

```
<?php
   foreach($item->clip as $value){
       echo $value['id'];
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Это не массив, а объект. Как следствие, к свойствам нужно обращаться используя нотацию `->`.

Например, для получения первого ID (`234`), подойдет вот такая конструкция:

```
$id = $obj->report->clip[0]->id;
```